# Problema al crear una función en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estoy aprendiendo JavaScript y necesito convertir estas dos líneas de código en una función.

```
var titulo = document.querySelector('h1');
titulo.innerHTML = 'Titulo modificado!'
```

Creé la función de la siguiente manera:

```
function actualizarTexto(){
var titulo = document.querySelector('h1');
    titulo.innerHTML = 'Titulo modificado!'
}
```

Pero no me funciona. He creado funciones que sí funcionan pero a esta en particular no le encuentro el error.

### Agrego parte del código

```
<body>
        <h1>Titulo 1</h1>
        <h2>Titulo 2</h2>
        <h3>Titulo 3</h3> 
        <h4>Titulo 4</h4>
<ul>
            <li>C#</li>
            <li>SQL Server</li>
        </ul>
        <p>Este es un párrafo </p>
        <ol>
            <li>Java</li>
            <li>Javascript</li>
        </ol>
<script>
//var titulo = document.write.querySelector('h1');
//          titulo.innerHTML = 'JS está en la casa';
//Convertir estas dos línes en una función a la que luego pueda llamar.

        function actualizarTexto()
        {
            var titulo = document.querySelector('h1');
            titulo.innerHTML = 'JS está en la casa';
        }

        </script>
        actualizarTexto();  
</body>
```

Comment: Muestra la parte de tú código de donde estás llamando a al función ActualizarTexto()

Comment: La función la llamo dentro del <body> <body/>

Comment: El error que me da es este: SyntaxError: function statement requires a name

Comment: Hola Pablo, hazle caso al error y ponle un nombre a la función.

Comment: Le acabo de agregar el nombre, ahora no me da ningún tipo de error pero sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta y coloca solo el código relevante pero completo para que alguien pueda responder correctamente tu pregunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La llamada a `actualizarTexto()` debe estar adentro del bloque `<script></script>` de lo contrario formará parte del HTML.

```html
<body>
  <h1>Titulo 1</h1>
  <h2>Titulo 2</h2>
  <h3>Titulo 3</h3>
  <h4>Titulo 4</h4>
  <ul>
    <li>C#</li>
    <li>SQL Server</li>
  </ul>
  <p>Este es un párrafo </p>
  <ol>
    <li>Java</li>
    <li>Javascript</li>
  </ol>
  <script>
    function actualizarTexto() {
      var titulo = document.querySelector('h1');
      titulo.innerHTML = 'JS está en la casa';
    }

    actualizarTexto();
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Gracias Carlos! Recién estoy empezando y es la primera vez que escribo código en JS, Voy a seguir practicando.

Answer (score 1):

Debes llamar a la función `ActualizarTexto();` en alguna parte para que se ejecute.
Por otro lado, te recomiendo escribir tus funciones y/o variables comenzando en minúscula. No cambia nada, pero es una convención. Sería así `function actualizarTexto()`.

Comment: La llamo justo antes de cerrar el body pero no me funciona. Gracias por el comentario.

Comment: Fijate que en el html sólo pusiste `function () { }`. No le pusiste nombre.

Comment: Acabo de editar el código tal como lo tengo actualmente. Ya le agregué el nombre.

Comment: Tu función la dejaste anonima, y en ningun punto la estas llamando. El tener el script dentro del body de esta forma no se va a ejecutar. Para que se genere el script necesita ser llamado después de algún evento de js.

Comment: Sólo la declaraste la función. Al declararla, no se ejecuta. Debes llamarla, como te indico más arriba, para que se ejecute. Quedaría así: 
`function actualizarTexto()
        {
            var titulo = document.querySelector('h1');
            titulo.innerHTML = 'JS está en la casa';
        }

actualizarTexto();`

Comment: Gracias TheWoodStudio, lo hice de esa forma pero no me funciona. LLamo a la función fuera del tag <scrpt> </script> y dentro del <body></body> pero no logro hacerlo funcionar.

Comment: Justamente, la llamada debe estar dentro del tag <script> </script>, de lo contrario no se tomará como JavaScript.

Comment: Gracias TheWoodStudio! Ahora si me funciona. Voy a seguir practicando.